# Can I know why commentary was deleted on this question?

Tags: support, deleted-comments

Here, my first comment got deleted. I asked the OP if he read the documentation he found and what wasn't clear... Any reason to delete that comment?

Obviously the documentation is quite clear about it.

The comment: *[What is the purpose of thisArg in .forEach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556558/javascript-foreach-what-is-the-purpose-of-thisarg?noredirect=1#comment56858361_34556558)*

Comment: I think this comment `@LoïcFaure-Lacroix blah blah blah – asdf_enel_hak` sould be deleted, not yours.

Comment: @J3soon that's my opinion too. The funny thing is that my comment had 3 upvote last time I saw.

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak: your comments are off topic. This question is not asking about whether or not your StackOverflow question is appropriate, but only whether or not his comment should have been deleted.

Comment: Perhaps they [the moderator] were meant to delete the `blah blah blah` comment, but instead accidentally deleted the useful one instead?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: IIRC, there's an auto-delete if a sufficiency of people flag the comment as "Rude or offensive" (don't know about "not constructive"). (It may only consider flags by people with a certain rep, I don't know the details.) So it could have been a mod, or just a group of users.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: ah yes, I keep forgetting about Mr. Community. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I remember being told earlier that [Community](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) is a Ms. ;)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder let's not forget how care-bear we're getting. Mentioning the documentation _at all_ probably rubbed some people the wrong way. Suggesting that people are lazy or that they've failed to comprehend a simple, obvious answer (ala documentation or lmgtfy) gets people angry... _particularly_ when it's true.

Comment: @canon: Indeed it does. :-) The MDN page *was* missing an actual example of using the arg, btw -- I fixed that. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder 3 of any flag can delete a comment (even other counts)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder good job for adding the examples... but still the polyfill should be more than enough to find how the arg is actually being used.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder obviously it's what I should have done.. Adding the example to the doc on MDN, and everybody would have been puzzled unless someone check at the history of changes  :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your comment was

> You found the documentation... did you read it? What's not clear?

It was flagged as being rude or abusive and deleted by a moderator. I wasn't the one who deleted it, but I can see how the "did you read it?" part could be read as being a little harsh.

I'll be honest, we don't spend a lot of time reviewing comments in response to flags, nor do we care to. We've been instructed that if a flagged comment could be read as being rude to someone else, and we see no compelling reason to keep it around, we're to delete it and move on.

We also get a lot of truly rude "RTFM"-style comments being flagged on a regular basis, so we're primed to delete comments of that style. Most of these don't add anything to the question asked, so they tend to be safe to delete.

If your comment had been slightly rephrased to

> What's not clear in the documentation you linked?

I would have declined a flag on that. Again, the "did you read it?" part gives your original comment a bit of an edge that could have been enough to make a moderator decide to delete it and move on. We've certainly seen a lot worse, but comments are pretty low on our list of things to worry about.

Comment: Again a comment deleted... why now?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix - I assume you mean the previous one here. No moderator deleted that one. It appears to have been automatically removed by the system in response to a "rude or abusive" comment flag and the presence of a trigger word that leads to automatic deletion. I'm guessing that word was "whore", but even moderators don't know the specific words on the list. I can't undelete the comment as a result.

Comment: But if that's that word how is your comment not getting triggered too... for autodelete or mods have super powers and can use swear words? Ah there is no specific list.. would be great to know.

Answer (score 1):

<s>It may have been deleted by a moderator</s> *(LOL, Brad was literally [answering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313849/157247) at the moment I was)*, but it may have been deleted by users.

According to the [comments FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/134069), in addition to the user deleting their own comment and a moderator deleting a comment, the community can:

> Comments that are flagged by multiple users are deleted automatically. The number of flags needed is based on the comment's score. It currently takes "3 + (Score / 3)" flags to delete a comment.

I didn't see your comment, but it's not that hard to attract three or four flags (particularly as we can be fairly sure of at least one of them, from his comments here).

Answer (score -18):

Since StackOverflow doesn't allow you to privately message mods, the best way to get their attention is to

1. flag a post/comment
2. select "Other" and briefly ask about your deleted comment and what you can do about it

This will enter your flag in the queue and the mods will eventually get to it (and hopefully answer you).

Comment: How does this provide an answer to the question? **The 'other' flag option shouldn't be directly used for asking why a particular flag was declined**. You *can* rephase the issue to something like 'I flagged this as x, but the flag was declined. This comment/question/answer/whatever should probably be removed as [reasoning].'.